# Laravel 5 & Vuejs Deploy to Production on Digital Ocean

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, vue.js, digital-ocean

I Laravel 5 and vuejs running in developement. Cannot seem to find good instructions on deploying live. Any suggestions or a link to a good tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

I developed a tutorial on how I deploy a Vue.js app to DigitalOcean

[Instructions](https://david.dukesnuz.com/blog/5/Website%20Development/deploy-a-vuejs-app-to-digital-ocean-droplet-with-github)

Comment: Issue solved. I believe I had a file named incorrectly. The first letter was in caps, should have been in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Capistrano for deploy. Here is link to Capistrano Laravel development setup ([capistrano/laravel](https://github.com/capistrano/laravel)).

If you feel Capistrano is complicated you can use simple git hook for development. There is a nice tutorial in the digital ocean. link for [How To Use Git Hooks To Automate Development and Deployment Tasks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks)

Make sure you to run yarn prod or npm run prod for javascript.